# Hyde LessCSS plugin doesn't convert less files to css

Tags: python, less, hyde, static-site

I've been trying to get a hyde site going using the latest version available (0.8.4). I used the built in command to create a site `hyde -s /path/to/dir create`, and all worked fine. I then followed some examples I found to try and get LessCSS support by editing the `site.yaml` file:

```
plugins:
    - hyde.ext.plugins.meta.MetaPlugin
    - hyde.ext.plugins.auto_extend.AutoExtendPlugin
    - hyde.ext.plugins.sorter.SorterPlugin
    - hyde.ext.plugins.tagger.TaggerPlugin
    - hyde.ext.plugins.syntext.SyntextPlugin
    - hyde.ext.plugins.textlinks.TextlinksPlugin
    - hyde.ext.plugins.less.LessCSSPlugin

# ...

less:
    app: /path/to/lessc
```

I added a very basic less file to check that it works:

```
/* content/media/css/style.less */
@color: blue;
body { background-color: @color; }
```

And included it in my application:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ media_url('css/style.css') }}">
```

When I generate the site, I see the the proper css in the command line output `body{background-color:blue};`, but the file `deploy/media/css/style.css` is just a copy of the `less` file. Documentation on this is not great - has anyone got it to work? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyde has an extensive test suite and the less css tests do pass. So the less plugin does work. The only issue I can think of is the `less` binary. Hyde's less plugin is written to be used with the JS version of less: https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/.